# What's the deal with $x^i$?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

Trying to get more [intuition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2503005/how-can-i-intuitively-understand-complex-exponents) on how exponentiation with complex numbers works, I began entering various functions with complex exponents into WolframAlpha. Both $e^{ix}$ and $i^x$ wasn't all that much of surprise, then I entered $x^i$ and...

[image: plot of x^i]

What the heck am I seeing? Supposedly in $e^{\theta i \pi}$ the $e$ is just a scale factor, chosen for convenience, so that argument would remain 1. Meanwhile, as scale factor the base doesn't behave all that nice either...

[image]

Could someone explain what's going on here?

Comment: I asked a similar question about the behavior of $^{-i}$: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2416196/471959 it should answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Euler's formula,

$$x^i=e^{i\log x}=\cos(\log x)+i\sin(\log x).$$

The argument is $\log x$, reduced to some $2\pi$ range.

There is no big mystery.

Comment: And the discontinuity of $arg( x^i )$ around 0.05? Why is it even negative? Or does WolframAlpha's `arg` mean something else than magnitude?

Comment: @SF.: I wrote "some $2\pi$ range", not really hard to figure out.